Check Plugin in different version
I am learning WordPress Plugin Development.
How to check a Plugin in different versions of WordPress ?

the core of wordpress is made in a way that it's better to update to the last version as soon as it is published. then just develop your plugin with the last version and take a look of the change log of future versions. but something else you can be careful about is the php version. php versions are more complicated to update on servers then you can develop you plugin in order to manage old version like 8.0 and 8.1. this can be done easily with docker e.g., docker allows you to stop a server and start another with another php version in a few seconds.
